# OCaml: how to use modules in Windows

Tags: windows, ocaml

I'm jus following [the tutorial](http://ocaml.org/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.html). It demonstrates the use of `Graphics`. It says

> [Windows users: For this example to work interactively on Windows, you
>   will need to create a custom toplevel. Issue the command ocamlmktop -o
>   ocaml-graphics graphics.cma from the command line.]

I don't exactly what it means.

I have corresponding source code in "D:\MySourceCode\OCaml\2.Graphics.ml". My cmd has entered OCaml environment. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine OCaml is installed in `C:\OCaml` and its libraries to `C:\OCaml\lib`. If I change directory to `C:\OCaml\lib` and execute `C:\OCaml\bin\ocamlmktop.exe -o graphics-toplevel.exe graphics.cma` I get `graphics-toplevel` executable with built-in Graphics module.  I can use `Graphics.open_graph "640x480"` directly without loading OCaml Graphics library.

Comment: I see...The tutorial produced `ocaml-graphics` without extension, so I don't know what it is.